# How to ensure Popup is visible inside a QML Map

Tags: qt, qml, coordinates, openstreetmap

I'm building a Qt **5.11** application which embeds an openstreetmap QML component.
I just wrote a minimal reproduce case. It consists in displaying objects (five blue dots here) on the map. When hovering the object, a small popup is displayed with some text.

When objects are close to the edge, the popup is not displayed correctly.
I though I would use [visibleArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#visibleArea-prop) check this, but the property was added in Qt 5.12.

I can't find a solution for the popup to be fully visible. Is there a workaround in Qt 5.11 that I can do?
Here the QML file. Just type `qmlscene sample.qml` and hover blue dots to view it.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtLocation 5.11
import QtPositioning 5.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    id: root; width: 800; height: 600;

    Plugin { id: mapPlugin; name: "osm"; }

    ListModel {
        id: myModel
        ListElement { latitude: 48.2351164;          longitude: 6.8986936;           name: "The point on the center"; }
        ListElement { latitude: 48.235111272600186;  longitude: 6.9007217756551995;  name: "The point on the right"; }
        ListElement { latitude: 48.23512783507458;   longitude: 6.896574932520792;   name: "The point on the left"; }
        ListElement { latitude: 48.23614708436043;   longitude: 6.898623901851295;   name: "The point on the top"; }
        ListElement { latitude: 48.23417574713512;   longitude: 6.898641104398024;   name: "The point on the bottom"; }
    }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(48.2351164, 6.8986936)
        zoomLevel: 19

        MapItemView {
            model: myModel

            delegate: MapQuickItem {
                anchorPoint.x: myRect.width / 2
                anchorPoint.y: myRect.height / 2
                width: myRect.width
                height: myRect.height

                coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(model.latitude, model.longitude)

                sourceItem: Rectangle {
                    id: myRect

                    readonly property int radius: 10

                    width: radius * 2
                    height: radius * 2
                    color: "transparent"

                    Canvas {
                        id: myCanvas
                        anchors.fill: parent

                        property alias textVisible: myPopup.visible

                        onPaint: {
                            var width = myRect.width;
                            var height = myRect.height;
                            var centreX = width / 2;
                            var centreY = height / 2;
                            var ctx = getContext("2d");
                            ctx.reset();
                            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.moveTo(centreX, centreY);
                            ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, myRect.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                            ctx.closePath();
                            ctx.fill();
                        }

                        MouseArea {
                            x: 0; y: 0;
                            width: myRect.radius * 2
                            height: myRect.radius * 2
                            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
                            hoverEnabled: true
                            onEntered: { myCanvas.textVisible = true }
                            onExited: { myCanvas.textVisible = false }
                        }
                    }

                    Popup {
                        id: myPopup
                        x: myRect.width / 2 - width / 2
                        y: myRect.height / 2 + 20
                        visible: false
                        Label { text: model.name; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for a while, I finally came across these two functions: [mapToItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method) and [mapFromItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapFromItem-method).

So, I first need to map the current item point to the `map` item coordinate system. Then, I must check the point is inside the map viewport.
If not, I have to adjust the coordinate, and after that, I map the point back to the current item coordinate system. Popup width and height seem to decrease when approaching bottom and right borders, so I had to use contentHeight, contentWidth and padding properties to get the real popup size.

And I had to initialize the popup x and y to a value different of zero to allow mouse event to pass on the blue dot.

Here is the working code, for those who may need it.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtLocation 5.11
import QtPositioning 5.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    id: root; width: 800; height: 600;

    Plugin { id: mapPlugin; name: "osm"; }

    ListModel {
        id: myModel
        ListElement { latitude: 48.2351164;          longitude: 6.8986936;           name: "The point on the center"; }
        ListElement { latitude: 48.235111272600186;  longitude: 6.9007217756551995;  name: "The point on the right"; }
        ListElement { latitude: 48.23512783507458;   longitude: 6.896574932520792;   name: "The point on the left"; }
        ListElement { latitude: 48.23614708436043;   longitude: 6.898623901851295;   name: "The point on the top"; }
        ListElement { latitude: 48.23417574713512;   longitude: 6.898641104398024;   name: "The point on the bottom"; }
    }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(48.2351164, 6.8986936)
        zoomLevel: 19

        MapItemView {
            model: myModel

            delegate: MapQuickItem {
                anchorPoint.x: myRect.width / 2
                anchorPoint.y: myRect.height / 2
                width: myRect.width
                height: myRect.height

                coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(model.latitude, model.longitude)

                sourceItem: Rectangle {
                    id: myRect

                    readonly property int radius: 10

                    width: radius * 2
                    height: radius * 2
                    color: "transparent"

                    Canvas {
                        id: myCanvas
                        anchors.fill: parent

                        property alias textVisible: myPopup.visible

                        onPaint: {
                            var width = myRect.width;
                            var height = myRect.height;
                            var centreX = width / 2;
                            var centreY = height / 2;
                            var ctx = getContext("2d");
                            ctx.reset();
                            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.moveTo(centreX, centreY);
                            ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, myRect.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                            ctx.closePath();
                            ctx.fill();
                        }

                        MouseArea {
                            x: 0; y: 0;
                            width: myRect.radius * 2
                            height: myRect.radius * 2
                            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
                            hoverEnabled: true

                            onPositionChanged: {
                                myCanvas.textVisible = true;

                                // absolute position in map coordinate system
                                var absPos = mapToItem(map, mouse.x, mouse.y);

                                // margin between mouse pointer and the popup
                                var cursorMargin = 10;
                                // extra margin for right and bottom side
                                var bottomRightSideExtraMargin = 10;

                                // add the cursor margin to the position
                                var absPopupX = absPos.x + cursorMargin;
                                var absPopupY = absPos.y + cursorMargin;

                                // adjust if the popup is out of view on the bottom or right sides
                                if (absPos.x + myPopup.contentWidth + myPopup.leftPadding + myRect.radius * 2 + bottomRightSideExtraMargin > root.width) {
                                    absPopupX = root.width - (myPopup.contentWidth + myPopup.leftPadding + cursorMargin + bottomRightSideExtraMargin);
                                }
                                if (absPos.y + myPopup.contentHeight + myPopup.topPadding + myRect.radius * 2 + bottomRightSideExtraMargin > root.height) {
                                    absPopupY = root.height - (myPopup.contentHeight + myPopup.topPadding + cursorMargin + bottomRightSideExtraMargin);
                                }

                                // convert back to the current item coordinate system
                                var popupPos = mapFromItem(map, absPopupX, absPopupY);
                                myPopup.x = popupPos.x;
                                myPopup.y = popupPos.y;
                            }

                            onExited: {
                                myCanvas.textVisible = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Popup {
                        id: myPopup
                        // original offset to allow mouse hover
                        x: 20; y: 20;
                        visible: false
                        Label { text: model.name; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if (**popup width+popup x**) goes outside screen width then change `x,y` to adjust popup position. You can look into following modified code for Popup component. adjust X and Y as per your marker position.

```
          Popup {
                    id: myPopup
                    x: {
                        if((mapItem.x+myPopup.width) >= root.width)
                           return -(myRect.width/2)-(width)
                        else if((mapItem.x-myPopup.width) < 0)
                           return (myRect.width)
                        else
                          return myRect.width / 2 - width / 2
                     }
                    y: {
                        if((mapItem.y+myPopup.height) >= root.height)
                            return  -(myRect.height/2)-(height)
                        else if((mapItem.y-myPopup.height) < 0)
                            return (height)
                        else
                            return myRect.height / 2 - height / 2
                     }
                    visible: false
                    Label { text: model.name;anchors.centerIn: parent;horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. It seems to not work on the right and bottom sides. I guess it is because the coordinates are in relative instead of absolute. I finally found a solution. I will post-it.